# iOS FBSDKGraphRequest won't return e-mail

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I've upgraded an iOS app from using v2.3 to using v2.7 but no matter what I try FBSDKGraphRequest won't return email address compared to the Android counterpart (it's authorized)

My login button

```
self.hiddenButton.readPermissions = @[@"email"];
```

Here's my request code

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, email"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result2, NSError *error) {
```

here is what it returns

```
{
    "first_name" = James;
    id = ********************;
    "last_name" = Mahy;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/**************/";
    name = "James Mahy";    
}
```

and these are the permissions the login says I have access to

```
(
    email,
    "contact_email",
    "public_profile"
)
```

I have tried the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31503463/555148 it doesn't change anything, I have tried recreating the app and still get the same problem.

I've also tried the same request on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cemail&version=v2.7 with multiple Facebook users and it just doesn't return email.

Appreciate your help
James

Comment: answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737695/facebook-graph-api-not-returning-email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was working, my e-mail address wasn't verified (although Facebook website said it was) so I had to add another e-mail account, verify it and then reset the original e-mail back to primary.

It worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

self.hiddenButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile",@"email"];