# Facebook Graph API not returning email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have the following code:

```
$fb = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => $appId,
    'app_secret' => $appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
]);

$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
$tokenMetaData = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
dump($tokenMetaData);

$graphUser = $fb->get('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email', $accessToken)->getGraphUser()->asArray();
dump($graphUser);
```

The output for the above is the following:

**$metaData**:

```
 [
   "app_id" => "..."
   "application" => "My App Name"
   "expires_at" => "2017-07-01 11:40:09.000000"
   "is_valid" => true
   "issued_at" => "2017-05-02 11:40:09.000000"
   "metadata" => array:2 [
     "auth_type" => "rerequest"
     "sso" => "ios"
    ]
    "scopes" => array:2 [
      0 => "email"
      1 => "public_profile"
    ]
    "user_id" => "102..."
  ]
}
```

**$graphUser**:

```
array:3 [
  "first_name" => "John"
  "last_name" => "Smith"
  "id" => "102...",
]
```

As you can see, the `scopes` in `$metaData` clearly has `email` so it isn't a permission issue. Despite this, the graph user *sometimes* does not have the email (although in some cases it does).

Why is this and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: The API will only returned confirmed email addresses. And there is a bunch of other factors such as privacy settings that can also influence this. So don’t write your app so that it _relies_ on getting an email address from the API. Lots of users don’t have one on file with Facebook, if they signed up using just their mobile.

Comment: @CBroe please write your comment as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: @YahyaUddin, Also, there are lots of user who actually signed up from their mobile phones & they don't have an email at all on their account. Quite old yet, might help somebody

Answer (score 20):

Add the fields you need to the URL of your request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,name
```

Comment: That's the right answer

Answer (score 7):

One possibility which i came across today is, if i am registering a account where i am not logging in using my `email ID`, may be using `mobile number` to `login`, and even in my profile `primary email` is not set or set to a `mobile number`, in this case `facebook` returns null for `email`.

I have updated the account and added email to `primary email` field under `settings` in `facebook page`, then i was able to get the `email id` from `facebook`.

Hope this helps someone.

Happy coding...

Answer (score 5):

First check if your access token gets the user's permission for the email

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?
  access_token=(access-token)
  &debug=all
```

if in the answer, this content does not appear:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "permission": "email",
            "status": "granted"
        },
        {
            "permission": "public_profile",
            "status": "granted"
        }
    ]
}
```

Maybe in obtaining your access token I do not request mail ownership: Add **scope=email** to the request

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.10/dialog/oauth?
  client_id=(app-id)
  &redirect_uri=(redirect-uri)
  &scope=email
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to check these steps.

1. check if your access token gets the user's permission for the email . for that login to your developer account of your app, then tools->graph api explorer then enable user's permission for the email.
2. check the facebook version, use the latest version.
3. add email scope in face book login script as below

   ```
   app.get(
       '/auth/facebook',
       passport.authenticate('facebook', {
         scope: ['user_location', 'email', 'user_friends']
       })
     );
   ```

   or

   ```
   FB.login(function(response) { 

      // your ajax script

   },{
       scope: 'email', 
       return_scopes: true
   });
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Goto your app > App review > Permissions and Features

Request Advanced access for email which should turn **Standard Access** into **Advanced Access**

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by specifying the graph api version.

My requested fields `first_name,last_name,email,picture`

To url: `https://graph.facebook.com/me`

Did NOT return email.

To url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me`

Did return email.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I specified the version, so that does not seem to be the issue

Comment: I also updated to the latest version but still it fails to return the email :/

Comment: I only get back name,id fields - not email

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer after selecting `Permissions > Add a Permission > email` you can access the Email address through the AccessToken you created by saying Generate Access Token.

```
var fbUrl = $"me?access_token={accessToken}&fields=name,email";
```

For test
[https://graph.facebook.com/me?'YourAccessToken'=name,email](https://graph.facebook.com/me?%27YourAccessToken%27=name,email)